# Anonymous table tags appearing in my page

Tags: html, css-tables, business-catalyst

I'm having difficulty trying to determine why an anonymous table format is appearing on my page, when I haven't coded it in, http://www.g7g20.com/partners.

I'm working in Business Catalyst and created a listing for my Webapp and created my own module template, as below:

```
<div class="partners"> 
    <a class="partners-link" href="{tag_website url}">{tag_logo_nolink}</a>
   <div class="partners-text"> 
 <a class="partners-link" href="{tag_website url}"><h2>{tag_name_nolink}</h2></a>
 <a class="partners-link" href="{tag_website url}"><p>{tag_description}</p></a>
<a class="partners-web-link" href="{tag_website url}">{tag_website}</a>
 </div>  
</div>
```

and my code for the page looks like this:

```
<div class="row content content-top">
            <div class="twelve columns top-pad">
        <div class="analysis-long-hd">CONTENT PARTNERS</div>
        {module_webapps,25234,c,30030,,,false,10,false,3 template="/ModuleTemplates/WebApps/partners-list.tpl"}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="analysis-long-hd">SPONSORS</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

But when I view the page through element inspector it appears that a table has been inserted and consequently shifted everything to the right and made the page non responsive.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us that code as it is rendered? (i.e., from the `View Source` menu option)

Comment: Here is the code for the view elements:

Comment: <table cellspacing="0" class="webapptable"><tbody><tr><td> the full code is too many characters

Comment: All sorted thank you